# Increment app badge number when push notification is received and app is not running

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm tired to solve this problem, I need to increment app badge number when app receive notification and not running. 
Thank for your help.

Comment: Unless you use a silent push notification you will need to se the correct badge number in the push notification from the server.

Comment: Thank @rckoenes, can't add good number from the server, because:
- I send push notification to a group user, not for one user :/
- For it, I must calculate a good number for each user

Comment: Then you will need background running for push notifications, which users can turn of, and silent push notifications to update the badge.

Comment: Background fetch will run when app is killed?

Comment: you need backend support. For example when User open the app, you can set the badge to 0 and report to backend. Next time you send notification to the user you can use badge value 1, and next time 2, and so on.